# Hierarchical foreign keys SQL +

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, foreign-keys

i'm trying to make a sqlplus database where cc has a foreign key to bb which also points to aa. With the code bellow i don't get any compilation error, but if the database is greater, it would be really tiresome to go son by son. is there any faster way to do this foreign key calls where c->b->a ... ? Thanks.

```
   create table aa(
name varchar(40),
country varchar(40),
constraint PK_aa PRIMARY KEY (name, country)
);

create table bb(
alias varchar(40),
aa_name varchar(40),
aa_country varchar(40),
aa_direction varchar(40),
constraint PK_bb PRIMARY KEY (alias, aa_country, aa_direction),
constraint FK_cc_bb FOREIGN KEY (aa_country, aa_direction) 
    references aa
);

create table cc(
id varchar(40),
bb_alias varchar(40),
bb_aa_name varchar(40),
bb_aa_country varchar(40),
constraint PK_cc PRIMARY KEY (id),
constraint FK_cc_cc2 FOREIGN KEY (bb_alias, bb_aa_name, bb_aa_country) 
    references bb
);
```

Comment: "tiresome to go son by son"? huh? General tip: composite foreign keys become VERY tedious when you could just have single field primary key in teach table and use that as the foreign key elsewhere.

Comment: i know, but sometimes the candidate key is a long one, and when doing the technique i use in the code is really tedious

Comment: I think Marc is partly referring to using a synthetic key, usually a numeric ID derived from a sequence (often populted by a trigger). Having a PK on `(name, country)` is rather restrictive in any case; you can't have two people with the same name in one country, really?